# What is the purpose of having three(or more?) directories with icons?

Tags: icons

All these folders contain icons.

- /usr/share/app-install/icons
- /usr/share/icons
- /usr/share/pixmaps

Comment: cweiske: that's not the same... the `s` refers to superuser so it's a seperation that's rather obvious: secturity and maintenance ;)

Comment: It's not as obvious as you think, and that still does not explain the difference between `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. It's always obvious when you know it.

Comment: @cweiske: that's why currently there are several proposals to merge `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, since whatever historical reason it had for separation is long gone, and now there is simply no point in having both. Fedora will soon replace `/bin` for a symlink. Solaris and Mac OSC have done already long ago, and I hope Ubuntu follows next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/share/app-install/icons` contains icons for installed applications. (`/usr/share/app-install/desktop/` contains `.desktop` files for applications)

`/usr/share/icons` are for themes.

`/usr/share/pixmaps` are for (gnome? (and kde?)) specific applications.

3 different things that each have their own usage and therefor each might have their own image. If you make a suggestion on, for instance, brainstorm or ayatana mailing list(?) someone might be inclined to give it a tought into merging them.
Me myself I like it when things are put into their own directory and there are all part of `/usr/share/` ;)

Maybe they'll be put together someday :)

Comment: Ok, and /usr/share/themes is also for themes? Where can I read about /usr/share layout?